# How to convert dates to UNIX timestamps in MomentJS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs

I want to convert my date time values to Unix timestamp format (basically an epoch timestamp). For that I use:

```
let startDate = '2018-09-28 11:20:55';
let endDate = '2018-10-28 11:20:55';
let test1 = startDate.unix();
let test2 = endDate.unix();
```

However it gives me an error

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'Unix' of undefined

Can anyone tell me how I can convert datetime to Unix using MomentJS?

Comment: Assuming `data.startDate` and `data.endDate` are references to Moment instance then your code should work fine. You need to double check exactly what those values are

Comment: Now you've updated the question you can see that the values are just plain strings you need to provide them to MomentJS instances. I added an answer showing you how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because you're calling `unix()` on plain strings. You need to instead call it on MomentJS objects. To create those, you can provide the date strings to a MomentJS constructor, like this:

```js
let startDate = '2018-09-28 11:20:55';
let endDate = '2018-10-28 11:20:55';

let test1 = moment(startDate).unix();
let test2 = moment(endDate).unix();

console.log(test1);
console.log(test2);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
```